# Is there something wrong with my SQL script?

Tags: sql, join

I'm doing the When Was the Golden Agen of Video Games challenge on Datacamp and i'm stuck on Task 6 - it asks me the following -

Select the year and avg_critic_score for those years that dropped off the list of critic favorites
-- Order the results from highest to lowest avg_critic_score

I tried multiple times and then tried the Show Answer script which generated following script but that is throwing an error

```
    SELECT g.year, COUNT(g.game) AS num_games, ROUND(AVG(r.user_score),2) AS 
     avg_user_score
      FROM game_sales g
       INNER JOIN reviews r
         ON g.game = r.game
       GROUP BY g.year
        HAVING COUNT(g.game) > 4
         ORDER BY avg_user_score DESC
                   Limit 10;
```

Error -  File "", line 1
SELECT g.year, COUNT(g.game) AS num_games, ROUND(AVG(r.user_score),2) AS avg_user_score
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Data source - https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/holmjason2/videogamedata

Comment: "but that is throwing an error" - Please include the error message in your post.

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: @Jens that's not true, [yes you can](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c4f5ad1dab7a3806a1100d6ad2bc33c6)

Comment: @juzraai this is the error - File "<ipython-input-69-a5c8b51ad808>", line 1
    SELECT g.year, COUNT(g.game) AS num_games, ROUND(AVG(r.user_score),2) AS avg_user_score
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: [mre] Please clarify via edits, not comments. [ask] [Help] PS When pinned down this will be a faq. [How  much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Limit 10; that's MySQL syntax and not SQL.

Use SELECT TOP(10) instead.

Comment: `top` is also product specific syntax and we don't know the OP's platform.

Comment: @Stu What do you mean? Title talks about SQL, tag is SQL and I mention that it is for SQL so I assume it's for SQL server managed database.

Comment: The only tag on this question is `SQL` - read its description. Where are you seeing *SQL Server*?

Comment: @Stu Fair enough.